# How to structure try/catch with async/await?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have the following code, simplified to leave out unnecessaries:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.put(url, {});
  if ( response.status === 200 ) {
    MicroService.action(data);
  }
} catch ( error ) {
  // user is not signed in, so send to create-account/sign-in
  if (error.status === 401) {
    MicroService.otherAction(data);
  } else {
    console.error(`The server returned an unexpected ${error.status} error upon attempting to hit ${url}`);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `catch` clause also catches any error that occurs in the fourth line, `MicroService.action(data)`. I *only* want to catch an error with the axios call on line 2, no other error should be silenced.

But if I take the `MicroService.action(data)` and move it to after the `catch`, then it happens even if the `try` fails, which is wrong. It should only happen if the `try` succeeds.

I could set a variable in the `try` clause, e.g. `if (response.status === 200) let success = true;`, and then check that variable after the `catch` clause. But that feels messy and inelegant for anything but the simplest possible case.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried placing a `finally` block after the catch?? That way it would execute after your axios call finishes. However, you would have to declare your `response` variable as a `let` and move it outside of your try. [MDN Try/Catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Syntax) Upon looking at the docs more, it does say that it would execute regardless if there is an exception or not. So this wouldn't solve the problem I think. *You could attempt to promsify the `Microservice.action(data)` call, and catch it in the try block.*

Comment: @EvanBechtol could also declare it inside the `try` as `var`.

Comment: I figured since OP appears to be using ES6 syntax, var would break the style consistency

Comment: @EvanBechtol if the intention is to initialize the variable inside the `try` and use it after the `catch` if there's no error (would need to return at the end of the `catch` block), then `var` is semantically the best choice since you're intentionally using a function-scope variable instead of a block-scope one.

Comment: So what do you want it to do with an error in your `MicroService.action(data);`?    If you want to ignore any error, (not a good idea),.. then you use another `try / catch` on this action.  Try and avoid doing just `try {....} catch () {}`, at least console log the error..

Comment: I’m not arguing that fact by any means. I’m simply saying that based on the code OP shared, ES6 syntax is clearly being used. Which is why I opted for `let` to be more consistent with overall style consistency that OP has already.

Comment: Also your subject `How to structure try/catch with async/await?`, the same way you  would do it if you wasn't using `async/wait`, and `axios.put` was a synchronous request.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts When I read the question, it didn't seem to be specific about axios at all. When I read your answer, I saw that an axios-specifc solution is the best approach in this case (+1), but the question itself still is a (quite good) duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid [vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) by overriding the [`validateStatus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors) callback. If a `401` status code is an expected outcome, then treat it like one and allow other unexpected status codes to throw as normal:

```
const response = await axios.put(url, {}, {
  validateStatus (status) {
    return [200, 401].includes(status);
  }
});

switch (response.status) {
case 200:
  MicroService.action(data);
  break;
case 401:
  MicroService.otherAction(data);
  break;
}
```

If you don't want any status codes to throw an error, then add a `default` case to the `switch` statement:

```
const response = await axios.put(url, {}, {
  validateStatus () {
    return true;
  }
});

switch (response.status) {
case 200:
  MicroService.action(data);
  break;
case 401:
  MicroService.otherAction(data);
  break;
default:
  console.error(`The server returned an unexpected ${response.status} error upon attempting to hit ${url}`);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1.
If this code is inside a function, you could move the `MicroService.action(data)` to after the try/catch and put a `return` in the catch (if applicable to the function).

2.
`then` syntax to call axios:

```
axios.put(url, {}).then((response) => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    MicroService.action(data);
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  if (error.status === 401) {
    MicroService.otherAction(data);
  } else {
    console.error(`The server returned an unexpected ${error.status} error upon attempting to hit ${url}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Trying to avoid then/catch syntax, deliberately trying to use es6 await syntax.

Comment: @temporary_user_name `await` is ES2017, not ES2015.